# How to speed up several asynchronous tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I have an array of mail objects fetched from an API. The goal is to create HTML files and save images for each mail.

For each mail I do the following tasks (all asynchronous):

- Fetch additional information of the mail.
- Download images from the API, convert them into base64, and write new files for the images.
- Build and write three HTML files.

The order of the processing matters. The api returns mail from newest to oldest, and I want them the other way around.

My code works but is slow. Currently each mail is blocked and needs to wait for the previous mail to finish. Ideally to improve speed, I want all the mails to process at once. I think the word for this is parallel processing?

```
// Rough skeleton of code, left out error handling
// Excuse any syntax/undefined errors, if any

async function fetchPaginatedMails() {
  let done = false;
  let page = 1;
  let allMails = [];

  while (!done) {
    const response = await thirdPartyApi(page);

    if (!response.hasNextPage) {
      done = true;
      break;
    }
    
    allMails = [...allMails, ...response.mails];
    page++;
  }

  return allMails.reverse(); // order mail from oldest to newest 
}

async localMailPaths(directory) {
  // recursive function that returns paths of mail HTML files in the local file system

  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(directory);

  const htmlFilePaths = await new Promise.all(
    files.map(file {
      const currentPath = path.join(directory, file);
      const stat = await fs.promises.lstat(currentPath);

      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        return localMailPaths(currentPath);
      }

      const parsedFile = path.parse(file);
      if (stat.isFile() && parsedFile.ext === '.html') {
        return file;
      }
    })
  );

  return htmlFilePaths.flat().filter((file) => file !== undefined);
}

async function downloadImage(directoryPath, imageUrl) {
  const response = await fetch(imageUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  const base64String = Buffer.from(response).toString('base64');
  await fs.promises.writeFile(directoryPath, base64String, 'jpeg');
}

async function createMailHTML(destinationPath, mail, mailContent, base64Images) {
   // uses JSDOM to build a HTML file of the mail
   // ...
   await fs.promises.writeFile(destinationPath, mailHTMLString);
}

async function createMailPreviewHTML(destinationHTMLFile, mail) {
 // uses JSDOM to build a mail preview, and adds it to the destination html file
 // ...
 await fs.promises.writeFile(destinationHTMLFile, mailPreviewHTMLString);
}

async makeDirectory(directory) {
  return fs.promises.mkdir(directory, { recursive: true });
}

async function processMails() {
  const outputDir = path.resolve('output');
  await makeDirectory(outputDir);

  const localMails = await localMailPaths(outputDir);
  const mails = await fetchPaginatedMails();
  
  for (const mail of mails) {
    const authorDir = path.resolve(outputDir, mail.author.name);
    await makeDirectory(authorDir);

    const mailPagePath = path.resolve(authorDir, `${mail.id}.html`);
    
    if (localMails.includes(mailPagePath)) {
      continue; // mail html file already exists
    }

    const mailContent = await thirdPartyApi(mail.id); // returns json
    const base64Images = await Promise.all(mail.images.map(async (imageUrl) => downloadImage(authorDir, imageUrl)));

    const indexPagePath = path.resolve(outputDir, 'all-mails.html');
    const authorPagePath = path.resolve(authorDir, 'author-mails.html');

    await createMailHTML(mailPagePath, mail, mailContent, base64Images);
    await createMailPreviewHTML(indexPagePath, mail);
    await createMailPreviewHTML(authorPagePath, mail);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for all API responses to complete before starting the real work of processing the mails, start processing a given mail immediately when its response comes back:

```
async function fetchPaginatedMails() {
    let page = 1;
    while (true) {
        const response = await thirdPartyApi(page);
        processMail(response.mails);
        if (!response.hasNextPage) {
            return
        }
    }
}

async function processMail(mail)) {
    const authorDir = path.resolve(outputDir, mail.author.name);
    await makeDirectory(authorDir);

    const mailPagePath = path.resolve(authorDir, `${mail.id}.html`);

    if (localMails.includes(mailPagePath)) {
        return; // mail html file already exists
    }

    const mailContent = await thirdPartyApi(mail.id); // returns json
    const base64Images = await Promise.all(mail.images.map(async (imageUrl) => downloadImage(authorDir, imageUrl)));

    const indexPagePath = path.resolve(outputDir, 'all-mails.html');
    const authorPagePath = path.resolve(authorDir, 'author-mails.html');

    await createMailHTML(mailPagePath, mail, mailContent, base64Images);
    await createMailPreviewHTML(indexPagePath, mail);
    await createMailPreviewHTML(authorPagePath, mail);
}

const outputDir = path.resolve('output');
await makeDirectory(outputDir);

const localMails = await localMailPaths(outputDir);
fetchPaginatedMails();
```

Comment: Just edited the post, but the processing order matters. The mails need to be processed from the oldest to newest created mail. (currently the api returns them from newest to oldest)

Comment: Can you explain where exactly in your code the order is important? Your functions are impure and many of them are missing implementation details, so I'm having a hard time guessing

Comment: I want the order to be preserved when saving a mail to the file system. I do this by first reversing the order of the fetched mails  (in the return statement of `fetchPaginatedMails`). And then inside the function `processMails`, I create and save a html file of the mail via `createMailHTML`. This way the saved mail HTML files are in the correct order in the file system

Comment: @annieg4123 You're giving the files a file name based on their id, can you use this to sort the files from the file system? I've no real idea about this stuff but it seems to me that trying to parrellise this process and do it in a specific order are somewhat conflicting aims.